# Understanding separating axis theorem and global / local coordinates

Tags: math

I'm having problems converting between local and global coordinates while projecting a rectangle onto different axes using the separated axis theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separating_axis_theorem. In the end, I'd like to check for collision with another object.

Let's say I have a rectangle with vertices in global coordinates of:

```
(10,20),(10,10),(20,10),(20,20)
```

The local coordinates would thus be:

```
(-5,5),(-5,-5),(5,-5),(5,5)
```

This would make the 4 normals the following: (1 for each axis)

```
(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1)
```

The min/max dot products for the would then be:

```
(1,0) . (-5,5)   = -5
(1,0) . (-5,-5)  = -5
(1,0) . (5,-5)   =  5
(1,0) . (5,5)    =  5
```

So the min/max pair for this normal is (-5,5), as are all the others in this case due to symmetry.

The problem comes when I want to convert the coordinates back into global coordinates. From my understanding, I need to shift the min/max pairs by the projection of the given axis onto it's global position.

This works fine when using the positive unit vectors:

```
unit    center of rect
(1,0) . (15, 15)        = 15
```

This means that the adjusted min/max values would be 15-5,15+5 = 10,20 which is correct

However, when I do this for the negative unit vectors, I get:

```
(-1,0) . (15, 15)      = -15, meaning that the min,max values are now (-20,-10)
```

I don't think this is correct? Is this how the algorithm is supposed to work?

Note: I'm trying to make the code work for all convex polygons, so I can't simply ignore the negative unit vectors for this rectangle.

Comment: Note: The article in Wikipedia is very imprecise, and the statement of the theorem is false. In R^2 take C1 = { (x,y), y <= 0} and C2 = { (x, y), x > 0 and y >= 1/x }. There is no line separating C1 and C2, they are disjoint and both are convex. For the theorem (it is called Hahn-Banach theorem in the literature) to be true, either C1 and C2 must be open, or C1 and C2 must be closed and at least one must be compact.

Answer (score 0):

You're simply failing to keep your coordinate frames straight. The `(-20, -10)` result is perfectly consistent and will give you the correct answer when you test the polygons for separation (along that axis).